# How get inner_html of ruby Nokogiri NodeSet unescaped?

Tags: ruby, nokogiri

I would like to get unescaped inner html from a Nokogiri NodeSet. Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 4):

Anything not okey with?

```
nodeset.inner_html
```

Answer (score 2):

The [loofah](https://github.com/flavorjones/loofah) gem helped me a lot here.

Answer (score 1):

Wrap your nodes in CDATA:

```rb
def wrap_in_cdata(node)
    # Using Nokogiri::XML::Node#content instead of #inner_html (which
    # escapes HTML entities) so nested nodes will not work
    node.inner_html = node.document.create_cdata(node.content)
    node
end
```

`Nokogiri::XML::Node#inner_html` escapes HTML entities except in CDATA sections.

```rb
fragment = Nokogiri::HTML.fragment "<div>Here is an unescaped string: <span>Turn left > right > straight & reach your destination.</span></div>"
puts fragment.inner_html
# <div>Here is an unescaped string: <span>Turn left &gt; right &gt; straight &amp; reach your destination.</span></div>


fragment.xpath(".//span").each {|node| node.inner_html = node.document.create_cdata(node.content) }
fragment.inner_html
# <div>Here is an unescaped string: <span>Turn left > right > straight & reach your destination.</span>\n</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

An old version of libxml2 might cause Nokogiri to return some escaped characters. I had this problem recently.